# SQL Query to get formatted result from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose,I have a table with 3 columns and 9 rows and I am using SQL Server 2008.

I want to write a SQL query  to get first three rows of data from the original table in one
row then from 4th row to 6th row get the data and put in the second row and so forth.

The table name is "Table1"

```
Primary_Key  | Name   |   Age

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


A   |       Kyle   |   45

B    |      Rob   |    66

C    |      Dhruba |   77

D    |      Susan  |   99

E    |      Steve    | 100

F    |      Mili   |   34

G    |      Grover  |  54

H     |     Alan    |   76

I    |      Paul    |  16
```

I am looking for this result after I run the query:(3 rows , 1 column)

```
ColumnA


+++++++++++++++

A, Kyle, 45, B, Rob,66, C,Dhruba,77

D,Susan,99, E,Steve ,   100,F, Mili, 34

G ,         Grover ,   54,H   ,      Alan ,     76,I   ,       Paul ,     16
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "get first three rows of data from the original table in one row". Are you planning to aggregate the 3 values of a column into 1 value?

Comment: Table definition, sample data and expected output would be really helpful. You also need to include a column that defines the order if the rows.

Comment: Not to mention the rules to follow in order to achieve the expected output :)

Comment: Do you have the option to do this in code?  If so, I wouldn't recommend using SQL Server to do this.

Comment: @Dhruba: Hmm! Are you really 77 years old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  Primary_Key char(1),
  Name varchar(10),
  Age int
)

insert into @T values
('A'    ,      'Kyle'   ,   45),
('B'    ,      'Rob'    ,   66),
('C'    ,      'Dhruba' ,   77),
('D'    ,      'Susan'  ,   99),
('E'    ,      'Steve'  ,  100),
('F'    ,      'Mili'   ,   34),
('G'    ,      'Grover' ,   54),
('H'    ,      'Alan'   ,   76),
('I'    ,      'Paul'   ,   16)

;with C as
(
  select *,
         (row_number() over(order by Primary_Key) - 1) / 3 as rn
  from @T
)
select stuff((select ', '+C2.Primary_Key+', '+C2.Name+', '+cast(C2.Age as varchar(10))
              from C as C2
              where C1.rn = C2.rn
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') as ColumnA

from C as C1
group by C1.rn 
order by C1.rn
```

Comment: Good attempt but this does not seem to work. Syntax issues I guess. Also thinking of using NTILE(3) instead of ROW_NUMBER

Comment: @Kash It does work. Try it here. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118181/

Comment: @Kash The insert statement of sample data requires SQL Server 2008 and the query requires SQL Server 2005 or higher. Using ntile(3) will only be correct if you have exactly 9 rows.

Comment: You are right, (RN-1)/3 would not depend on # of rows. Regarding the query, i am not able to execute it right on SQL Server 2008. Which engine does the SO Data Explorer usually use?

Comment: I keep getting this error in SQL Server 2008 R2: _Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'_ for the from in the query in stuff.

Comment: @Kash Do you have two parenthesis at the end of the first line in the sub query `))`?

Comment: Yes, which belongs to the CAST function. What does type & value do in this case?

Comment: @Kash type makes the query return an xml data type and value fetches the only value from the xml (the concatenated string). There are answers provided to these kinds of questions using `for xml path('')` not using that technique but they will run into trouble if some value contains any XML unfriendly characters like `& < >`.